# How to use pan gesture on mutiple UIImageView

Tags: uiview, uiimageview, gesture, multiview

I develop app that have many view but when i want to move certain view (backgndView) using pan gesture, the other view was moved. Seem my desired view not active. Here the code.

```
//---pan gesture---
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture =
[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
 initWithTarget:self
 action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];

[backgndView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[frameView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[effectView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[itemView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[extraView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release];
```

I think extraView is active for gesture but not other view. Any other way to make selected view active?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didnt understand problem well but something like blow makes all views active for pan gesture.

//---pan gesture---

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture =
[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
 initWithTarget:self
 action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];

[backgndView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release]; 

panGesture =
[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
 initWithTarget:self
 action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
[frameView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release]; 

panGesture =
[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
 initWithTarget:self
 action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
[effectView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release]; 

panGesture =
[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
 initWithTarget:self
 action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
[itemView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
[panGesture release]; 

panGesture =
[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
 initWithTarget:self
 action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];
[extraView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];

[panGesture release];
```